# Bloquear escritura en input si el nombre es muy ancho con e.preventDefault(); no funciona

Tags: jquery

Tengo un script en jquery que valida si el nombre de usuario introducido es mas ancho que "WWWWWWWWW". Hasta ahora, el script muestra un aviso cuando es demasiado ancho, pero me piden que bloquee la escritura a partir de la decima W y la vuelva a permitir si borran y el nombre cumple el ancho. El problema sería que no llega a bloquear la escritura.

```
$('html').on('keyup touchend',function(e){if(e.keyCode == 8)checkPassword();checkUsername();}) 
var eventhandler = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();      
}
  function checkUsername(){
      var username = $('#usuario').val();
        var ajaxurl = "acciones/checkUsername.php?username="+username;
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            cache: 'false',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.username == "no") {
                    $("#usuario").css("border","2px solid green");
                    $(".usedError").css("display","none");
                    $(".sendform").css("opacity","1");
                    $(".sendform").attr("disabled",false); 
                    setTimeout(function() {
                     var uwidth = $('#measure').val();
                     if (uwidth > 136) {
                          $(".userinput").css("border","2px solid red");
                          $(".longError").css("display","block");
                          $(".sendform").css("opacity","0.5");
                          $(".sendform").attr("disabled","disabled");
                          $('#usuario').bind('submit', eventhandler);
                      } else if (uwidth == 152) {
                          $(".userinput").css("border","2px solid green");
                          $(".longError").css("display","none");
                          $(".sendform").css("opacity","1");
                          $(".sendform").attr("disabled",false);
                          $('#usuario').unbind('submit', eventhandler);
                      } else if (uwidth == 0) {
                          $(".userinput").css("border","thin solid #a5a5a5");
                          $(".longError").css("display","none");
                          $('#usuario').unbind('submit', eventhandler);
                      } else {
                          $(".userinput").css("border","2px solid green");
                          $(".longError").css("display","none");
                          $(".sendform").css("opacity","1");
                          $(".sendform").attr("disabled",false);
                          $('#usuario').unbind('submit', eventhandler);
                      }
                    }, 300);
                } else if (response.username == "si") {
                    $("#usuario").css("border","2px solid red");
                    $(".usedError").css("display","block");
                    $(".sendform").css("opacity","0.5");
                    $(".sendform").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
                } else {
                    $("#usuario").css("border","thin solid #a5a5a5");
                    $(".usedError").css("display","none");
                    $(".sendform").css("opacity","1");
                    $(".sendform").attr("disabled",false); 
                }
            },
            error: function() {
              
            }
        });
  }
<input type="text" class="userinput" id="usuario" name="usuario" maxlength="21" onKeyUp="checkUsername();" required/>
              <span class="longError" style="display:none;color:red;"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> El nombre de usuario es demasiado ancho. (WWWWWWWWW)</span>
              <span class="usedError" style="display:none;color:red;"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> El nombre de usuario ya esta en uso.</span>
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que no permita la escritura cuando cumple el ancho y si la permita si borra y el ancho lo permite?

Comment: Sé cómo hacerlo en JavaScript, ¿te interesa?

Comment: @EdgarSaavedra Me vendría bien en javascript también

Answer (score 0):

Para bloquear la escritura después del décimo carácter, te podría ayudar el siguiente código JavaScript:

```
function validarUsuario(e) {
    if(e.value.length > 10) {
        e.value = e.value.substring(0, e.value.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Y en tu INPUT quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="text" class="userinput" id="usuario" name="usuario" onkeyup="validarUsuario(this)" onkeydown="validarUsuario(this)" required/>
```

Espero y te sirva amigo :)